# Very basic PHP - IF AND IF...?

Tags: php

My current code is as follows:

```
if ( ( $status == 'active' ) || 
     ( $status == 'full' ) ) {
```

I need to also include an AND statement. So if $status is either full or active AND $position matches 'need photo' or 'completed' then it displays. How do I include an AND statement?

I tried the following but it didn't seem to work:

```
if ( ( $status == 'active' ) || 
     ( $status == 'full' ) && 
     ( $position == 'need photo' ) || 
     ( ( $position == 'completed' ) ) {
```

Any help? Thank you! :-) I'm fairly new to all of this. I tried Google but couldn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||` so the code you tried is the same as:

```
if ($status == 'active' || ($status == 'full' && $position == 'need photo') || $position == 'completed') {
```

Which in plain English means, if either `status` is `active`, or both `status` is `full` and `position` is `need photo`, or `position` is `completed`.

But you want:

```
if (($status == 'active' || $status == 'full') && ($position == 'need photo' || $position == 'completed')) {
```

Which means, if either `status` is `active` or `status` is `full`, and either `position` is `need photo` or `position` is `completed`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PHP documentation on operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), `AND` takes precedence over `OR`, so you need to group the `OR` expressions with parentheses:

```
if ( ($status == 'active || $status == 'full) && ($position == 'need photo' || $position == 'completed') ) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing some brackets.  What you want is `if ((A) && (B))`, where A and B are complex expressions (an expression containing two sub-expressions).

In your case: A = `( $status == 'active' ) || ( $status == 'full' )` and B = `( $position == 'need photo' ) || ( $position == 'completed' )`

So, try this:
`if ( **(** ( $status == 'active' ) || ( $status == 'full' ) **)** && **(** ( $position == 'need photo' ) || ( $position == 'completed' ) **)** ) {`

Comment: ** is just to highlight the changes, don't put them in your code:
So copy and past this:

`if ( ( ( $status == 'active' ) || ( $status == 'full' ) ) && ( ( $position == 'need photo' ) || ( $position == 'completed' ) ) ) {`